# Strip Ascent and special characters

Tags: xslt-2.0

Hi I am trying to remove both ascent and special characters with the following xslt i have written, seems ascent characters are getting stripped but not the special characters. Is there anyway that we can add another translate function to remove special characters on the existing translate one that is stripping ascent characters. following is the xml input and  xslt for your reference.

```
       <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Testing">
       <wd:Report_Entry>
       <wd:EmployeeID>12345</wd:EmployeeID>
       <wd:FirstName>Åntony</wd:FirstName>
       <wd:MiddleName>Ma'rcia</wd:MiddleName>
       <wd:LastName>Ðorean</wd:LastName>
       </wd:Report_Entry>
       </wd:Report_Data>


  **XSLT for the above xml input**

      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Testing" 
       xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"
       xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv" 

       xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.
       ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
      xmlns:this="this.file/eib" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-
      result-
      prefixes="xs this wd">

      <xsl:output method="text"/>

      <xsl:variable name="LineFeed" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="Comma" select="','"/>
       <xsl:variable name="original" 
      select="áàâäåãéèêëíìîïóòôöúùûüÃÅÄÆæñØõøÜðÐÓğżŁęłŁńąÅÁńº/
       ¤•’();∙,¨-.'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="ascii" 
      select="aaaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuAAAEenOooUdDOgzLelLnaAAn"/>
      <xsl:variable name="replace" select="'"/>
       <xsl:template match="/">
    
        <Record >
            <Header>
                >
                <FirstName>FirstName</FirstName>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Comma"/>
                <FirstName>MiddleName</FirstName>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Comma"/>
                <LastName>LastName</LastName>                          
                <xsl:value-of select="$LineFeed"/>                    
                </Header>                
                <xsl:for-each 
     select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">                                       
                <File>
     <xsl:value-of select="translate(wd:FirstName, $original, 
     $ascii)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Comma"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="translate(wd:MiddleName, 
      $original,$ascii)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Comma"/>                        
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(wd:LastName, $original, 
       $ascii)"/>
               </File>
                <xsl:value-of select="$LineFeed"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>    

  I am trying to achieve below result with the above xslt where i am 
  able to strip ascent but not    
  special characters

  Current Name format

  First Name -  Åntony
  Middle Name-  Ma'rcia
  Last Name  -  Ðorean

  Expected Format 

  First Name -  Antony
  Middle Name-  Marcia
  Last Name  -  Dorean


 Do let me know for any additional information if needed on this.
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us a minimal but complete example to reproduce the issue but for the word `Ma'rcia` the apostrophe `'` seems to be missing in your list of `original`. And there is some odd whitespace or formatting in your code samples, I would your original list to be e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="original" select="áàâäåãéèêëíìîïóòôöúùûüÃÅÄÆæñØõøÜðÐÓğżŁęłŁńąÅÁńº/¤•’();∙,¨-.'"/>
```

and then the shortened one to be

```
<xsl:variable name="ascii" select="aaaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuAAAEenOooUdDOgzLelLnaAAn"/>
```

In your comments you indicate that you want to replace some special characters through spaces, but I also think you want to drop any single quote `'`, so perhaps

```
<xsl:variable name="original" select="'áàâäåãéèêëíìîïóòôöúùûüÃÅÄÆæñØõøÜðÐÓğżŁęłŁńąÅÁńº/&#10;¤•’();∙,¨-.'''"/>
<xsl:variable name="ascii" select="'aaaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuAAAEenOooUdDOgzLelLnaAAn              '"/>
```

helps.

Unfortunately your posted code snippets are not usable as posted due to some formatting problems.
Note also that in XSLT/XPath 2 and later some unicode normalization and replace of accent classes might save your from listing all those letters.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your response. I did try to add apostrophe ' in the original, but it was erroring out, and the long space is for replacing each special character with space.

Comment: @Alex, post a minimal but complete example of XML input and XSLT to allow us to reproduce the error.

Comment: Martin, i have added xml input and the xslt for it.

Comment: @Alex, see whether the edit helps.

Comment: thanks for inputs. I see error but i am trying to find a fix. will let you know if i am not able to fix. Thanks much for looking into it.